# updating and saving an existing blob/file in blobstore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

The docs are pretty clear about how to create/get a blob, but I can't find any reference to how to modify and save an existing blob.

Is this actually possible given the BlobInfo object?

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore

Comment: yes you can use this procedure in the question to create and process blobs in blobstore.

Comment: ?? don't understand your answer...

Comment: :I mean you can process any file as you want then save it on the blobstore.

Comment: :you can't edit the blob itself, you can edit any file then save it on the blobstore in order to serve it.

Comment: would you show me how or give me a link where i can see that? how would you update a blob created by the blobstore files api and save it instead of replacing it?

Comment: Can you specify what type of editing you want?, i tried for example compressing multi uploaded files in zip file then store it on the blobstore.

Comment: write a dictionary into the blobstore via files api, save it to an entity, retrieve that entity, update the dictionary and write the file back.

Comment: i think my question is pretty clear... not sure if you understood it though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot modify an existing blob.

You can use the [Files API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore) to read from an existing blob and write to a new blob.

If you don't want to use the Files API to read the existing blob then you can use a [BlobReader](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobreaderclass).

Comment: thx. thats was i was thinking. ill keep replacing the blobs on update like i did till now.

Answer (score 0):

I use http://tsssaver.1conan.com to save blobs. You put in your info, and it sends a request for all signed firmwares.

You do not need to be on the version to save blobs, blobs are just a small file from Apple’s servers that use some of your device’s info and their encryption key to verify a restore.

Assuming you want to save your blobs for your current iOS no longer signed by apple hoping you could future restore it, you are out of luck as you may only be able to save your blob at your end but you can't obtain Apples encryption key to verify and perform the restore for future use.